# Python payroll calculation issue

Tags: python

I have everything working accept when i calculate overtime it does the regular pay wrong.
where is my error I've been trying to figure out how to make it work for hours. If i put in 45 hours it has my regular pay X 45 not 40.

```
def main():

    hours, rate = getinput()

    strtime, overtimehr, overtime  = calculate_hours (hours,rate)

    regular, totalpay  = calculate_payregular (hours, rate, overtime)

    calprint  (rate, strtime, overtimehr, regular, overtime, totalpay)


def getinput():

    print ()
    print ('How many hours were worked?')
    print ('Hours worked must be at least 8 and no more than 86.')
    hours = float (input('Now enter the hours worked please:'))

    while hours < 8 or hours > 86: #validate the hours
        print ('Error--- The hours worked must be atleast 8 and no more than 86.')
        hours = float (input('Please try again:'))

    print ('What is the pay rate?')
    print ('The pay rate must be at least $7.00 and not more than $50.00.')
    rate = float (input('Now enter the pay rate:'))

    while rate < 7 or rate > 50: #validate the payrate
        print ('Error--- The pay rate must be at least $7.00 and not more than $50.00.')
        rate = float (input('Please try again:'))

    return hours, rate

def calculate_hours (hours,rate):

    if hours < 40:
        strtime = hours
        overtimehr = 0
    else:
        strtime = 40
        overtimehr = hours - 40

    if hours > 40:
        overtimerate = 1.5 * rate
        overtime = (hours-40) * overtimerate
    else:
        overtime = 0

    return strtime, overtimehr, overtime

def calculate_payregular (hours, rate, overtime):

    regular = hours * rate

    totalpay = overtime + regular

    return regular, totalpay


def calprint (rate, strtime, overtimehr, regular, overtime, totalpay):

    print ("           Payroll Information")
    print ()
    print ("Pay rate                $", format (rate,  '9,.2f'))
    print ("Regular Hours            ", format (strtime,  '9,.2f'))
    print ("Overtime hours           ", format (overtimehr,  '9,.2f'))
    print ("Regular pay             $", format (regular,  '9.2f'))
    print ("Overtime pay            $", format (overtime,  '9.2f'))
    print ("Total Pay               $", format (totalpay,  '9.2f'))

main ()
```

Comment: In your test, what were the value of `rate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because `hours` is never being redefined.

In `main()` you get the value of `hours` from `getinput()` - which is the total hours both *standard* and *overtime*.

`hours` is passed to `calculate_hours()`, but is never changed in the scope of main if it is over 40. So when you call `calculate_payregular()` the raw value of `hours` (which may be over 40) is passed in.

You can fix this, as `calculate_hours()` returns a normal-rate time in the returned variable `strtime`, so if you change this:

```
regular, totalpay  = calculate_payregular (hours, rate, overtime)
```

to this:

```
regular, totalpay  = calculate_payregular (strtime, rate, overtime)
```

It should calculate it correctly.

Comment: Ok now im confused even more.

Comment: Oh i had it setup to always do the hours no matter what instead of strtime. Which i see if it was 40 or below hours worked just fine but for 40+ it would do all the hours. Thanks alot

Comment: @Bigslimm21 No worries. If the answer helped, you can click the up arrow to indicate this, and if an answer solved your problem you can indicate this by clicking the green tick.

If the answer *didn't* help you can also click the down arrow, but I hope that isn't this case this time!

Comment: It wont let my click up but you helped alot